# Youtube Api + Fancybox + Autoplay playing without opening video

Tags: jquery, video, youtube-api, fancybox-2, autoplay

I have a video that is initial hidden inside a div on pageload. Then when I click an image it opens and auto plays.

However, when flash is not enabled on the browser the video plays without being opened. So I can just hear the audio, but no video.

Here is the Youtube Api code I'm using:

```
<div id="video-home-popup" style="display:none; padding:0px;">
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            playerVars: {
                modestbranding: true,
                theme: 'light',
                rel: 0,
                wmode: "opaque",
                autoplay: '1'
            },
            height: '480',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'qLFQUdmAkcQ',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        /// event.target.playVideo(); 
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Paused',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Watch to End',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
</div>
```

Fancybox code:

```
var vid=jQuery;
vid.noConflict();
    vid(document).ready(function() {
        vid('.fancyboxvideo').fancybox({
            padding : 0,
            openEffect : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',
            autoSize    : false,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '640px',
            height      : '480px',
            arrows : false,
            wmode       : 'opaque',
            helpers : {
            media : {},
            buttons : {},
            overlay : {
            css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Link to open video:

```
<a class="fancyboxvideo" href="#video-home-popup"></a>
```

Comment: Which browser? I just tested with the latest Firefox and Chrome and the video didn't autoplay.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to have (hidden) inline videos, they add an overhead to your page load. Why don't you call the video (in fancybox) until you really need it visible? Here is an example how-to within the `beforeShow` callback

Comment: @ViniciusPinto My apologies - I posted the code with autoplay set to 0. I have changed it to 1.

Comment: @JFK The reason I had to use this implementation method is so my Google Analytics tracking would work on the video.

Comment: @WolfCat : your analytics will work anyways since you are pushing the events inside the `onPlayerStateChange()` function

Comment: @JFK I don't quite understand how to use beforeShow. Could you please explain? I couldn't find it in fancyapps docs.

Answer (score -1):

The `autoplay` option should be zero, just call `player.playVideo()` on the `onComplete` Fancybox callback.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the issue ;) ... also, check the tags of the question, it says `fancybox-2` and `onComplete` is NOT a valid option for that version.

Comment: Care to explain? I agree with your comment in the OP saying that it's better to load the video only when it's needed, but if he wants to load it hidden, what's wrong with using playVideo()? (besides the callback name, which I believe is `afterShow` in the new version)

Comment: the OP says `when flash is not enabled on the browser`;  `playVideo()` doesn't seem to solve the issue in this scenario

Comment: I just tested on the latest Chrome and FF, it works fine. I think IE must be version 8 or later, not sure about Safari.